# What is the curve complex of the 5-times punctured sphere?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, combinatorial-geometry, simplicial-complex, mapping-class-group

There are many theorems about connectedness and other such properties of the curve complex of the 5-times punctured sphere. However, I cannot find any explicit descriptions of the curve-complex. (By explicit, I probably mean information that could mindlessly compute a "drawing" of its 1-skeleton in 2 or 3 dimensional space.)

My attempts to do this myself are as follows: Consider the disk in the plane with four punctures placed symmetrically (say $(1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)$). (This is topologically a sphere with five punctures). Using the geometry of the plane, each isotopy class of essential simple closed curves has a "length" defined as the infimum of lengths of curves in the isotopy class. Using this notion of length, subgraphs $C_r$ of the curve complex $C$ can be drawn:
$$C_r = \{v \in C: l(v) \leq r\}.$$
Drawing graphs for small $r$, we obtain the following:
$$C_7 = \text{petersen graph}$$
$$C_{11} = \begin{cases}\text{connected graph with } 30 \text{ vertices}\\ \text{girth } 5\\ \text{each vertex contained in a cycle of length } 5\\ 10 \text{ vertices degree } 5, \text{ rest degree } 3.\end{cases}$$
I suspect $C_{11}$ embeds in a $(5,5)$-cage. This is interesting since $C_7$ is the unique $(3,5)$-cage. However, I still feel very distant from knowing what the full curve complex of the 5-times punctured sphere is.

Comment: I don't think this is quite true, because the Farey graph is the curve complex of $S_{0,4}$ in the sense of "there is an edge whenever the minimum intersection number is achieved" (which in the case of $S_{0,4}$ is $2$, rather than $0$ for $S_{0,5}$). In fact, one can show that the girth of $\mathcal C(S_{0,5})$ is necessarily $5$, which is pretty cool. I hope I can find a nice picture at some point!